# How can I test a future that is bound to a tokio TcpStream?

Tags: rust, future, rust-tokio

I have a future which wraps a TCP stream in a `Framed` using the `LinesCodec`.

When I try to wrap this in a test, I get the future blocking around 20% of the time, but because I have nothing listening on the socket I'm trying to connect to, I expect to always get the error:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker-0' panicked at 'error: Os { code: 111, kind: ConnectionRefused, message: "Connection refused" }', src/lib.rs:35:24 note: Run with 'RUST_BACKTRACE=1' for a backtrace.
```

This is the test code I have used:

```
#[macro_use(try_ready)]
extern crate futures; // 0.1.24
extern crate tokio;   // 0.1.8

use std::io;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::codec::{Framed, LinesCodec};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::prelude::*;

struct MyFuture {
    addr: SocketAddr,
}

impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Item = Framed<TcpStream, LinesCodec>;
    type Error = io::Error;
    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Framed<TcpStream, LinesCodec>>, io::Error> {
        let strm = try_ready!(TcpStream::connect(&self.addr).poll());
        Ok(Async::Ready(Framed::new(strm, LinesCodec::new())))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::net::Shutdown;

    #[test]
    fn connect() {
        let addr: SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:4222".parse().unwrap();
        let fut = MyFuture { addr: addr }
            .and_then(|f| {
                println!("connected");
                let cn = f.get_ref();
                cn.shutdown(Shutdown::Both)
            }).map_err(|e| panic!("error: {:?}", e));
        tokio::run(fut)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6087d956493ffeb9087413db16ad4077&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015%20link)

I have seen patterns in other languages where the test binary itself offers a mechanism to return results asynchronously, but haven't found a good way of using a similar mechanism in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to test async code may be to use a dedicated runtime for each test: start it, wait for future completion and shutdown the runtime at the end of the test.

```
#[test]
fn my_case() {

    // setup future f
    // ...

    tokio::run(f);
}
```

I don't know if there are consolidated patterns already in the Rust ecosystem; see [this discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/issues/1169) about the evolution of testing support for future based code.

### Why your code does not work as expected

When you invoke `poll()`, the future is queried to check if a value is available.

If a value is not available, an interest is registered so that `poll()` will be invoked again when something happens that can resolve the future.

When your `MyFuture::poll()` is invoked:

1. `TcpStream::connect` creates a new future `TcpStreamNew`
2. `TcpStreamNew::poll` is invoked immediately only **once** on the future's creation at step 1.
3. The future goes out of scope, so the next time you invoke `MyFuture::poll` you never resolve the previously created futures.

You have registered an interest for a future that, if not resolved the first time you poll it, you never ask back again (poll) for a resolved value or for an error.

The reason of the "nondeterministic" behavior is because the first `poll` sometimes resolve immediately with a `ConnectionRefused` error and sometimes it waits forever for a future connection event or a failure that it is never retrieved.

Look at `mio::sys::unix::tcp::TcpStream` used by Tokio:

```
 impl TcpStream {
     pub fn connect(stream: net::TcpStream, addr: &SocketAddr) -> io::Result<TcpStream> {
         set_nonblock(stream.as_raw_fd())?;

         match stream.connect(addr) {
             Ok(..) => {}
             Err(ref e) if e.raw_os_error() == Some(libc::EINPROGRESS) => {}
             Err(e) => return Err(e),
         }

         Ok(TcpStream {
             inner: stream,
         })
     }
```

When you [`connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) on a non-blocking socket, the system call may connect/fail immediately or return `EINPROGRESS`, in this last case a poll must be triggered for retrieving the value of the error.

Comment: maybe this answer need a little upgrade? Using tokio 1.0 and compiler says: "tokio::run(f);
(run) not found in `tokio`"

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not with the test but with the implementation.

This working test case based on yours has no custom future implementation and only calls `TcpStream::connect()`. It works as you expect it to.

```
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::net::Shutdown;
    use std::net::SocketAddr;
    use tokio::net::TcpStream;
    use tokio::prelude::*;

    #[test]
    fn connect() {
        let addr: SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:4222".parse().unwrap();
        let fut = TcpStream::connect(&addr)
            .and_then(|f| {
                println!("connected");
                f.shutdown(Shutdown::Both)
            }).map_err(|e| panic!("error: {:?}", e));
        tokio::run(fut)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=32fe325b2b81934f6c7728a93fec87c7&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

You are connecting to the same endpoint over and over again in your `poll()` method. That's not how a future works. The `poll()` method will be called repeatedly, with the expectation that at some point it will return either `Ok(Async::Ready(..))` or `Err(..)`.

If you initiate a new TCP connection every time `poll()` is called, it will be unlikely to complete in time.

[Here is a modified example that does what you expect](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=29c418f13af85f21c7a218cd0f795ae6&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
#[macro_use(try_ready)]
extern crate futures;
extern crate tokio;
use std::io;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use tokio::codec::{Framed, LinesCodec};
use tokio::net::{ConnectFuture, TcpStream};
use tokio::prelude::*;

struct MyFuture {
    tcp: ConnectFuture,
}

impl MyFuture {
    fn new(addr: SocketAddr) -> MyFuture {
        MyFuture {
            tcp: TcpStream::connect(&addr),
        }
    }
}

impl Future for MyFuture {
    type Item = Framed<TcpStream, LinesCodec>;
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn poll(&mut self) -> Result<Async<Framed<TcpStream, LinesCodec>>, io::Error> {
        let strm = try_ready!(self.tcp.poll());
        Ok(Async::Ready(Framed::new(strm, LinesCodec::new())))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::net::Shutdown;

    #[test]
    fn connect() {
        let addr: SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:4222".parse().unwrap();
        let fut = MyFuture::new(addr)
            .and_then(|f| {
                println!("connected");
                let cn = f.get_ref();
                cn.shutdown(Shutdown::Both)
            }).map_err(|e| panic!("error: {:?}", e));
        tokio::run(fut)
    }
}
```

I'm not certain what you intend your future to do, though; I can't comment if it's the right approach.

Comment: While i think this answer is really high quality too, I thought the accepted one shows an approach to achieve running futures in a harness, which is more valuable to me, and better targeted at the question. I was about to accept your answer, when I saw the other one come in, and it was a close call, because I do recognize that you answered first and correctly. I am sorry if this is a disappointment to you, and am really grateful for your response.

Answer (score 1):

to some degree, you can drop in tokio's test library to make this easier; it supports async/await in unit tests.

```
#[tokio::test]
async fn my_future_test() {
  let addr: SocketAddr = "127.0.0.1:4222".parse().unwrap();
  match MyFuture { addr }.poll().await {
    Ok(f) => assert!("something good")
    Err(e) => assert!("something bad")
  }
}
```

https://docs.rs/tokio/0.3.3/tokio/attr.test.html